# Xamarin PDF View crashed the app in android 8.1 (8.1.1)

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, pdf-viewer

In xamarin application user a xamarin pdf viewer to show some pdfs. It is work with android 8 and bellow versions. But when in android 8.1 try to open it, It will cause to crashed the application

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? For example,do you get any exception? Or  what's your xamarin pdf viewer? You could try to use webview to show the pdfs.

Comment: Joanzapata Pdfview
OS - 8.1 +